# C++ Qt application working but gives warning "qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method"

Tags: c++, ssl, https, qt5, qt-creator

I have written a C++ Qt application (QtCreator version 4.8 based on Qt 5.12.0) running on Linux mint version 18.3 that makes use of QNetworkAccessManager and related classes. It is basically a Betfair HTTPS client application that communicates with the Betfair servers. I have openSSL installed (version 1.0.2g).

Basically my application works perfectly, but I get the **qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method** (twice) on the application output tab in QtCreator. I am able to successfully login and interact with the API - everything looks and behaves well! I have even used wireshark to inspect the packets which certainly look to be encrypted.

I have seen other answers on here and on the web saying that Ubuntu ships openSSL with disabled openSSLv2 due to instability and recommendations for recompilation WITH openSSLv2 enabled. But as my application is actually working, I am uncertain if this is necessary?

Basically my question is what are the implications of this warning to my software (which appears to be working exactly as intended) in regards to security? I really don't want to ignore a warning without knowing what it is there for. I only know the basics of how SSL works so am a little out of my depth in knowing how to proceed here.

**EDIT:** Some answers have led me to discover that the warning is triggered at the point in which a QSslKey is created from my key file. Actual code causing it is:

```
QByteArray keydata = kfile.readAll();
QSslKey pkey(keydata,QSsl::Rsa);   // Warning fires after this line executed
if(pkey.isNull()) {
    qWarning("The key has no content.");
}
```

Comment: Basically, Qt cannot use the preferred SSLv2 protocol of the server because you haven't compiled OpenSSl with v2 enabled. Then, qt + server roll back to SSLv1 and everything works as expected..

Comment: @Tezirg Thanks for the reply. Are there any major security flaws or areas to be concerned about with this usage of SSLv1 ??? Clearly the best solution will be to recompile openSSL with SSLv2 enabled.

Comment: No clue, but I wouldn't worry too much. Maybe I'm careless tough

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I can't give you a full answer but I can give you some material to investigate.

In your Qt installation folder check the file qtnetwork-config.h
It contains flags that will enable/disable code Qt code depending on your platform packages available on the time Qt was configured (using /qtsrc/configure) or build on your system.

Example of my qtnetwork-config.h file:

```
#define QT_FEATURE_networkinterface 1
#define QT_FEATURE_bearermanagement 1
#define QT_FEATURE_ftp 1
#define QT_FEATURE_http 1
#define QT_FEATURE_localserver 1
#define QT_FEATURE_networkdiskcache 1
#define QT_FEATURE_networkproxy 1
#define QT_NO_OPENSSL true
#define QT_FEATURE_sctp -1
#define QT_NO_SCTP 
#define QT_FEATURE_socks5 1
#define QT_FEATURE_ssl -1
#define QT_NO_SSL 
#define QT_FEATURE_udpsocket 1
```

If your ssl packages changed after you've build Qt (e.g. you upgraded/downgraded or deleted some ...) will these settings still be valid? I'm unsure. What happens when you deploy a pre-build Qt? ...

This could be investigated further.
Anyway, to find out what is causing the warning install a messagehandler:

```
// put this in main.cpp for instance
void myMessageOutput(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &/*context*/, const QString &msg)
{
    if (msg.contains("cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method"))
    {
        qDebug() << "put a breakpoint here and look in the stack trace where you are";
    }
}
// put this in int main(int argc, char ** argv) for instance
qInstallMessageHandler(myMessageOutput);
```

Run your application in debug with Qt build in debug from source.
You should hit the breakpoint in the message handler and see the origin of the message.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but unfortunately I KNOW why I get the message (openSSLv2 disabled in the ubuntu openSSL packages) and how to overcome it (recompile from source a version of openSSL with v2 enabled). I really need to know how the security of my application is affected if I leave things as they are.

Answer (score 0):

All versions minor to TLSv1.2 such as TLSv1.0 and SSLv1.0 SSLv2.0 are deprecated and should not be used or supported any more. Since a lot of servers and clients are out there which do not specify their minimal requirement for a TLS version Ubuntu disabled these really old and insecure protocols. You can read more about it here: [TLSv1.1 must die die die](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/06/19/ietf_calls_for_formal_tls_1_0_1_1_deprecation/).

Depending on the version of QNetworkManager / Qt that you are using a statement such as this should make the warning go away and greatly improve the security of the encryption of the secured socket.

```
QNetworkRequest request(url);
QSslConfiguration config = request.sslConfiguration();
config.setProtocol(QSsl::TlsV1_2);
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer which has helped me to identify that it is actually creating a QSslKey instance from my key file that is the source of the warning.